# length function in nawk command

Tags: shell, unix, nawk

I have the nawk command to validate if the length is greater than 12 then mark number has $

I need to use the same below command by adding one more condition i.e length should be greater than 12 and less than 17

```
nawk ' length($7) > 12 {$7=substr($7,1,6)"$$$$$$$$} 1 ' FS=\| OFS=\|
```

Comment: You're missing a double quote in the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
(length($7)>12) && (length($7)<17)
```

Should do it